# Работа с массивами python 3

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, список

Вопрос следующий, почему когда я создаю массив таким образом:

```
x = [[]]*3
```

И после добавлю элемент через метод append. Например так:

```
x[0].append(1)
```

То получиться в итоге такой вот массив:

```
[[1],[1],[1]]
```

Но, если я задам этот массив изначально в такой форме:

```
x=[[],[],[]]
```

То используя все тот же метод append, как я указал выше, то получу вот такой массив:

```
[[1],[],[]]
```

Почему так происходит ?

Answer (score 6):

В этом случае список на 3 элемента, и в каждом элементе ссылка на один и тот же список.

```
x = [[]] * 3
```

Поэтому, выражение `x[0].append(1)` имеет результат: `[[1],[1],[1]]`

Если есть желание проверить мое утверждение, запустите код `print([hex(id(i)) for i in x])` и увидите что `id` объектов в списке одинаковые, т.е. это один и тот же объект.

С учетом написанного, для создания списка списков используйте такой код:

```
x = [[] for _ in range(3)]
x[0].append(1)
print(x)  # [[1], [], []]
```

---

Думаю, этот код создания списка (`x = [[]] * 3`) разворачивается в такую конструкцию:

```
value = []
number = 3
x = [value for _ in range(number)]

x[0].append(1)
print(x)
```

Поэтому, использование в такой синтаксической конструкции изменяемых типов, такие как списки не рекомендуется. Используйте простые неизменяемые типы например: строки, числа, булевые значения и т.п.

Например:

```
x = [9] * 3
x[0] = 1
print(x)  # [1, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

День добрый.
В первом случаи ты создаешь массив состоящий из 3-х элементов, каждый из которых ссылается на один и тот же объект (они являются копиями). Поэтому изменяя любой из элементов массива, ты изменяешь объект на который они ссылаются. Во втором случаи все элементы являются разными объектами.